# Displaying trailing zeros except when a whole number

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way (in .NET) of removing trailing zeros from a number when using `.ToString("...")`, but to display to 2 decimal places if the number is not a whole number:

1. (12345.00).ToString(...) should display as 12345
2. (12345.10).ToString(...) should display as 12345.10
3. (12345.12).ToString(...) should display as 12345.12

Is there 1 number format string that will work in all these scenarios?

`.ToString("#.##")` nearly works but doesn't show the trailing 0 for scenario 2...

Also, other cultures aren't an issue, i just want a decimal point (not a comma etc.)

Comment: Try `0.#0`?  I haven't tried this and I am not sure how it will react in the whole number situation.

Comment: There isn't a single format for this.  Also, what do you want 12345.001 to display as?  12345.00 (round to 2 decimals because it's not a whole number) or 12345 (the number rounded to 2 decimals is a whole number, so remove trailing zeroes)?

Comment: For whole numbers this displays as 12345.00

Comment: @Joe this is a good point which i missed, i'm essentially displaying cash amounts, so i don't want to show "12345.00". So my question isn't actually about whole numbers, it's about not displaying ".00" (which means i'll need to use a slightly different solution)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something along these lines?

```
            if (number % 1 == 0)
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:0}", number));
            else
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:0.00}", number));
```

EDIT

There is a little bug in this code though:) 1.001 will be printed as "1.00"... this may not be what you want, if you need to print 1.001 as "1" you'll need to change the if(...) test to check for a finite tolerance. As this question is more about the formatting I will leave the answer unchanged but in production code you might want to consider this kind of issue.

Comment: For slightly more readable code, I would prefer `String format = (number % 1) == 0 ? "{0:0}" : "{0:0.00}";`

Comment: Yes, I did go with that initialy but I thought the "long way" was clearer in the context of answering the question. I would probably use your style in real code.

Comment: It's not quite what I was looking for, as I wanted to bind directly to the number on an asp.net page, and use the format string to determine how it is displayed.  I have, however, used this approach to add another variable to my bindings, and bind to that (as a string) instead.

Answer (score 3):

Dirty way:

```
string.Format("{0:0.00}", number).Replace(".00","")
```

Comment: This approach returns 110 for 11.0

Answer (score 2):

Not in one format but it fits in one line:

```
double a = 1.0;
string format = string.Format((a == (int)a) ? "{0:0}" : "{0:0.00}", a);
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't say I've come across a single mask that will do that. I would use

```
string output = (value % 1 > 0) ? String.Format("{0:0.00}", value) : String.Format("{0:0.##}", value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write an extension method like this to do the formatting for you:

```
public static string FormatNumberString(this double input)
    {
        int temp;
        string inputString = input.ToString();
        return Int32.TryParse(inputString, out temp) ? inputString : input.ToString("0.00");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were looking to do this in ASP MVC Razor then you could try this

```
@string.Format(item.DecimalNumber % 1 == 0 ? "{0:0}" : "{0:0.00}", item.DecimalNumber)
```

This will behave like so:

Value: 2.5 --> Display: 2.50

Value: 5 --> Display: 5

Value: 2.45 --> Display: 2.45

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do your very own method to produce that display, since it's conditional to whether or not it is an integer.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToCustomString(this decimal d)
    {
        int i = (int)d;
        if (i == d)
            return i.ToString();

        return d.ToString("#.00");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it to display currency, you can use following

```
float fVal = 1234.20f;
String strVal = fVal.Tostring("c");
```